# Comparing sets of randomly assigned codes in Java to assign a name

Tags: java, set, comparison

Good day,

I honestly do not know how to phrase the problem in the title, thus the generic description. Actually I have a set of ~150 codes, which are combined to produce a single string, like this "a_b_c_d". Valid combinations contain 1-4 code combinations plus the '-' character if no value is assigned, and each code is only used once( "a_a..." is not considered valid). These sets of codes are then assigned to a unique name. Not all combinations are logical, but if a combination is valid then the order of the codes does not matter (if "f_g_e_-" is valid, then "e_g_f_-","e_f_-_ g_" is valid, and they all have the same name). I have taken the time and assigned each valid combination to its unique name and tried to create a single parser to read these values and produce the name.

I think the problem is apparent. Since the order does not matter, I have to check for every possible combination. The codes cannot be strictly orderd, since there are some codes who have meaning in any position.So, this is impossible to accomplish with a simple parser. Is there an optimal way to do this, or will I have to force the user to use some kind of order against the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TreehMap to store the code (string) and and its count (int). increment the count for the code every time it is encountered in the string.

After processing the whole string if you find the count for any code > 1 then string has repeated codes and is invalid, else valid.

Traversing TreeMap will be sorted based on key value. Traverse the TreeMap to generate code sequence that will be sorted.

Comment: Checking for validity is not my concern actually. If the code inputted is not found in the availlable codes, then it is invalid. I will still check for double codes to invalidate it before searching for the assignment, but this is the easy part.

Comment: What is you goal here? To check if the given string is valid? or to generate all possible combinations?

Comment: The goal is to retrieve the name of the combination. There are combinations of these values (including some of those code alone, p.ex. "a_-_-_-" that correspond to a name. p.ex. "a_b_c_d"--->"Red" , "e_f_g_-"--->"Blue" etc. These values do not change if the code positions change, "e_f_g_-"="g_e_-_f"="-_f_g_e"=....---->"Blue"

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Use a TreeMap, it is similar to HashMap except that it will be sorted on key.